# Difference between *array and array[0] when calculating number of array elements in C

Tags: c

For the given array:

```
int array[10];
```

What is the difference between

```
sizeof array / sizeof *array
```

**and**

```
sizeof array / sizeof array[0]
```

when calculating the number of elements in `array`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is none in this case. Both ultimately results in the type `int` because in the first case array decays into pointer to the first element when used as an operand of `*`(You are dereferencing a `int*`).

Note one thing - you might have heard that on `sizeof` there is no decay of arrays but here the decay happens when array is used as operand to `*`. The operand for `sizeof` is simply `int`. (Discussing about `sizeof arr/sizeof *arr`)

In case you want to get a clear idea - try this

```
int a[10][20];
printf("%zu %zu\n",sizeof a/ sizeof *a, sizeof a/ sizeof **a);
```

---

Your second case is WYSIWYG type of thing - what I mean by this, it just says total size of the array and divide it with what it contains (the size of it). And yes it would return the size of the array. That is what is being done.

`arr[0]` is nothing but `*(arr+0)` means `*arr`. So that makes sense and they are same.

---

Few points that will clarify things (If you later use `sizeof`)

<sub>`array` and `&array[0]` is same in this context. Their value and type both will be same. But For pointers being the same value is just one thing - their implication on the pointer arithmetic is a whole different story.</sub> 


<sub>`int a[10][20];` Here `a` and `&a` and `a[0]` all has same value but their type is different and since pointer arithmetic is closely coupled with what it points to. It matters.</sub>

Comment: @ClintPachl.: Yes that's why I said,,,why `array` is pointing to first element and dereferencing it is `int`. There are 4 cases 1) sizeof 2) Alignof 3) & 4) Initialization of literal...where decay doesn;t happen. Do you want me to edit ? I don't get youpoint.

Answer (score 5):

The expression `array[n]` is by definition the same as `*(array + n)`

The expression `array + 0` is by definition the same as `array` (unless `array` is an operand of `sizeof`).

So yes, `array[0]` and `*array` are the same.

This is much more than is needed in this case. For arguments of `sizeof` only the type matters, and it is certainly the same for both expressions.

Comment: Strange but I said this ***same*** thing. I wonder what matters here. All the very best. Don't take the comment other way. (Maybe you can share some thing regarding the thing I am talking about - *what matters most?*)

Comment: "`array + 0` is by definition the same as `array`".  Hmmm, the type and size of `array + 0` and `array` differ.

Comment: @chux yes a an exception clarified.

Answer (score 1):

**For some additional information:**

In C the reference to the start address of the array is given by the name **without** the brackets []:

`array`

At the array address the first element is listed in memory, so both :

`*array` and `array[0]` give the first element of the array.

Moreover, these addresses will also be equal:

`array == &array[0]`